# Como habilitar o CORS em projetos Java com a implementação do JWT?

Tags: java, react, java-ee, cors, jwt

Estou fazendo um projeto web service, onde eu implementei o JWT e para consumir usando Reactjs eu habilitei o CORS, porem quando faço uma requisição que precisa ter o token, esta retornando isso: Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8080/teste/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

Se for uma requisição GET, mas não precisa do token, ele consome normal.

Quando usa o JWT precisa ser feito algo alem de criar a classe de filtros (ContainerResponseFilter)?

```
@Provider
public class CORSResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {
@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext,
ContainerResponseContext containerResponseContext) throws IOException {
containerResponseContext.getHeaders().add(
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000");
containerResponseContext.getHeaders().add(
"Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
containerResponseContext.getHeaders().add(
"Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
"origin, X-Requested-With, content-type, accept, Authorization");
containerResponseContext.getHeaders().add(
"Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
"GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O erro do browser `Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status` indica o endpoint http://localhost:8080/teste/ não está retornando o código **HTTP 200 OK** para a chamada do método **HTTP OPTIONS**.

Verifique o log da sua aplicação por erros nesse endpoint, corrija os erros encontrados e teste novamente.

Comment: Ao debugar o web server feito em java, me deperarei que classe na JWTFilter  no trecho; String authorizationHeader = requestContext.getHeaderString(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION); Esta Null, será que o problema ta na forma que eu to enviando o token?

Comment: É possível sim. Editar a pergunta, adicionando o request que está sendo enviado, vai auxiliar a melhorar a resposta :)

Comment: Tem como por citar um exemplo usando reactjs por favor?